# HP Procurve 5406ZL - How to enable port-mirroring?

Tags: network-monitoring, hp-procurve, port-mirroring

How would you enable port mirroring for a HP Procurve 5406ZL?

The [configuration guide](http://cdn.procurve.com/training/Manuals/3500-5400-6200-8200-CLI-K_14_09.pdf) is not very clear in the mirror-port function. I know that I'll need to use the `mirror-port [[ethernet] PORT-NUM]` but it don't know (or how) should I go specifying the target port to be mirrored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the target to be monitored using the monitor command page 385 in your book.

**Usage:** 
[no] monitor mac MAC-ADDR  mirror <1-4 | NAME-STR>

**Description:** 
Set up traffic monitoring for a given MAC address. Network
traffic with this MAC address as the source or destination is
**copied to the mirror port**.

**Parameters:**
MAC-ADDR - MAC address to be monitored

- Type of traffic to monitor:
src - Monitor traffic with MAC-ADDR as the source.
dst - Monitor traffic with MAC-ADDR as the destination.
both - Monitor traffic with MAC-ADDR as the source or destination.

<1-4> - Mirror destination number

NAME-STR - Friendly name associated with the mirror destionation number.

This may also help

[How to configure remote and intelligent mirroring 
on ProCurve switches](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02640590)

Comment: The issue was resolved by the client's network vendor. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Link is dead (403 forbidden)